# Обработка события SelectionChanged элемента listbox и вывод определенных данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Каким образом можно извлечь данные при выборе элементов.

```
private void list_box_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e) // list_box - это элемент listbox
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(list_box.Items["Adress"].ToString());

    }
```

Есть listbox элемент в него добавляться элементы.
Сам код добавления:

```
     public class connect_to_bd
    {
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Addres { get; set; }
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string Cam { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<connect_to_bd> connect_to_bd = new List<connect_to_bd>();
        connect_bd_device(connect_to_bd);
        list_box.DataContext = connect_to_bd;
    }

  ///Сама функция 
  private List<connect_to_bd> connect_bd_device(List<connect_to_bd> connect_to_bd)
    {
    ... 
    connect_to_bd.Add(new connect_to_bd() { ContactName = s1, Cam = s2, Addres = s3, Server = s4, id = db });
    }
```

### XML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Имя:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactName}" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Адрес:" Foreground="DarkOrange" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Addres}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Сервер:" Foreground="DarkOrange" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Server}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Камеры:" Foreground="DarkOrange" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cam}" />
            </DockPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


 <Grid>
<ListBox x:Name="list_box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="269" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" Width="398" SelectionChanged="list_box_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создать публичное свойство типа `connect_to_bd` и привязать `SelectedItem` к этому свойству, а событие выбора выкинуть нафиг.

Comment: @Bulson можете написать код, пожалуйста. я примерно представляю что  public List<connect_to_bd> connect_to_bdd = new List<connect_to_bd>(); и далее по событию берем index

Comment: ну вроде как работает int t = list_box.SelectedIndex;
            MessageBox.Show(connect_to_bdd[t].ContactName);

Comment: Используйте [привязку данных](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php).